# How can I pass my form by parent component to child component (MobileItems to Accessories Items)?

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

Mobile Items is parent component

AccessoryItems is child component

Mobile Items has a reactive angular form and how can i pass that to another form to accessory component.

Mobile Items html and component code into one component and same for accessory item component.

Comment: Please add some code so we can understand your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using the Dependency Injection of Angular

In your AccessoriesItemsComponent child component, just use the viewProviders parameter to inject the parent form in your child view like this :

```javascript
@Component({
  /* ... */

  // In case of Template driven form
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
  // In case of Reactive form
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective } ]
})
export class AccessoriesItemsComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whole form from parent (`accessoryComponent`) to child (`mobileItemComponent`) with an input like :

parent.ts

```js
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    login: ['', Validators.required],
    password: [null, Validators.required]
  });
}
```

parent.html

```html
<child [parentForm]="form"></child>
```

child.ts

```js
@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
```

child.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
   <!-- Here you can access form controls -->
</form>
```

Comment: how to do i acesss controls in html of child?

Comment: @JayMehta I updated my code with child.html file. Please check

Comment: but for accessing controls into child html we do need to create new form into child.ts otherwise it wont allow you to access those controls which were defined into parent.ts

Comment: What do you mean by "controls" ? Please add some code to give us exactly what you need to do.

Comment: <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="accessoryN1Id">Accessory Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" id="accessoryN1Id" type= "text" placeholder="Accessory Name (required)"
            formControlName="accessoryName">
        </div>

Comment: here FormControlName is giving me error like UNable to find controls